# from parent to child without traversing the full path

Tags: javascript, jquery

My divs are nested like this.

```
<div id="top">
   <div class="child1">
      <div class="child-child">
         <div class="child-child-child">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>   
   <div class="child2">
      <div class="child-child">
         <div class="child-child-child">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>   
</div>
```

Right now I'm going from `#top` to `.child-child-child` by doing this.

```
$('#top').children('.child1')
         .children('.child-child')
         .children('.child-child-child');
```

Do I have to specify the full path like this? I want to omit the middle divs if there's a syntax that would let me do that. But I probably still need to specify whether I want to go through `.child1` or `.child2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do need to specify which path to take, but you could make it a little shorter:

```
$('#top > .child1').find('.child-child-child');
```

This will give you the `'.child-child-child'` that is a descendant of `.child1`.

Or you could write it like this, using [only selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

```
$('#top > .child1 .child-child-child');
```

Or this, using only [traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/):

```
$('#top').children('child1').find('.child-child-child');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) (a space) to find the child anywhere beneath (as [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) does), like this:

```
$('#top .child-child-child');
```

Or, a bit more specific:

```
$('#top > .child1 .child-child-child');
```

Answer (score 1):

To simplify this, you can use the selector:

```
$('#top .child1 .child-child-child');
```

This selector says "an element with a class of `.child-child-child` that is inside an element with a class of `.child1` that's inside an element with an id of `top`".